# how to fill the series in JqPlot?

Tags: charts, jqplot

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var l0 = [6,  11, 10, 13, 11,  7];
    var l1 = [3,   6,  7,  7,  5,  3];
    var l2 = [4,   8,  9, 10, 8,   6];
    var l3 = [9,  13, 14, 16, 17, 19];
    var l4 = [15, 17, 16, 18, 13, 11];

    var plot1 = $.jqplot("chart1", [l0, l1, l2, l3, l4], {
        title: "Fill between 2 lines",
        axesDefaults: {
            pad: 1.05
        },

        fillBetween: {
            series1: 1,
            series2: 3,
            color: "rgba(227, 167, 111, 0.7)",
            baseSeries: 0,
            fill: true
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            rendererOptions: {
                smooth: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

this example shows fill between 2 series.
i need to fill the series 1,2 and 3,4 .
stacked fill is not met my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is still not present. I have worked on this enhancement of this code.
[Bitbucket pull request link for the enhancement](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/pull-request/51/changes-made-to-incorporate-an-array-of/diff)

The code change in this link will help you solve your problem.

After making the code change, pass an array of values for series1 and series2 for fillbetween property:

```
 fillBetween: {
        series1: [1,3],
        series2: [2,4],
        color: "rgba(227, 167, 111, 0.7)",
        baseSeries: 0,
        fill: true
    }
```

this way you will be able to fill the series 1,2 and 3,4 .

Comment: Thankyou very much for your enhancement! I have ported it to Github. https://github.com/jqPlot/jqPlot/pull/34